# Why progress-bar doesn't work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a simple basic progress-bar it works if I add just one progress element in my *HTML* page but if I added another one, first works very well but second not as expected.

Here's my [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/pbKBpX)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="ani-progressbar">
    <div class="fill-progress" kac-puan="8">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ani-progressbar">
    <div class="fill-progress" kac-puan="10">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**:

```
.ani-progressbar{
  width:100%;
  height:5px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.fill-progress span{
  display:block;
  width:5px;
  height:5px;
  border:1px solid #9ad204;
  float:left;
  margin-left:1px;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var getVal = $(".ani-progressbar .fill-progress").attr("kac-puan");
  $(".ani-progressbar .fill-progress span").slice(0,getVal).each(function(index,element){

   $(this).css("background","#9ad204");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your *jQuery* function as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ani-progressbar .fill-progress").each(function() {
        var getVal = $(this).attr("kac-puan");
        var thisParent = $(this);
        thisParent.children('span').slice(0, getVal).each(function(index, element) {
            $(this).css("background", "#9ad204");
        });
    });

});
```

- Your function will only get the `attr` of first encountered *progress-bar* instead of that you have to get `attr` of each *progress-bar* i.e. why it only works for first not for the other ones.
- Secondly you can simply take current *progress-bar* into a variable `thisParent` and `slice` all the `children` *span* elements as per there *kac-puan* `attr` value.

Here I have updated your [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/vivekkupadhyay/pen/qNwjpb)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are getting all `span` elements and slice them. So only first one works properly.

Check here for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hrv27bx3/